# Передать зашифрованную информацию

Tags: сеть, передача-данных, nfc

Как можно передать зашифрованную информацию? Допустим, есть флешка его проводят над каким то полем и чтобы информация между флешкой и раздатчиком информации обменялась.. Должно быть что-то на подобии qr кодов. но должны быть очень безопасными, чтобы никто не смог взломать, никто не смог передать какую то другую информацию. Если что непонятно задавайте вопросы в комментариях, отвечу!

Comment: хм..каким образом это связано с программированием и тематикой форума?

Comment: а в какой форум это надо было писать?у хешкода есть такой?

Comment: Понятия не имею, на какой, но явно не на этот

Comment: программисты занимаются безопасностью информации...так что можно и программистам=Ъ они же могут предложить способ передачи..Мне кажется нормально

Comment: знаете, программисты также иногда обедают, завтракают и ужинают. Может, тогда вопрос "как приготовить бифштекс?" тоже стоит здесь задавать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFC, RFID

Comment: NFC на слишком маленькие расстояния. RFID подходит, но как с безопасностью?

Comment: Любое софтварное шифрование, от AES до Triple DES

Answer (score 0):

Вы имеете ввиду передачу информацию с флешки куда-то посредством электромагнитных волн что ли? Если это так, то почитайте учебник физики за 9 класс, откройте для себя понятие частоты колебаний и осознайте, наконец, что флешка на то и флешка, что информация с нее передается посредством прямого контакта с USB разъемом =)

Comment: мне нужно чтобы за очень короткое время передалось несколько килобайтов информации без проводов.

Comment: не вай фай...допустим пучком света..чтобы передача была прямолинейная

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте! Почему бы не использовать RFID HF (13,56 МГц)? Вы наносите метку на нужное изделие и затем можете считать ее с помощью RFID-считывателя.
Плюсы:
- возможность разработать алгоритм шифрования меток при их программировании, который будет известен только Вам;
- малое расстояние считывания, позволяет также визуально идентифицировать нужную для считывания метку;
- относительно невысокая стоимость решения;
- большой ассортимент типов и размеров меток.